# header fixed top doesnt work on section bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have `header` with `top-bar` and `nav` using bootstrap 4.

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <header class="fixed-top">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="container">
        top bar
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Test</h2>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

I add `fixed-top` class on `header`, Now In action `header` is over of `section` and `section` not show after `header`. how do can i show `section` after `header` block?!

[image]

demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2mvnLo3d/)

Comment: I suggest you to not use `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<article>`, `<section>` tags with BootStrap. Better to stick with regular `<div>` elements

Comment: These tags has some CSS associated with them on the other hand `<div>` tag just create an empty container.

Comment: section { margin-top: 75px } would help